# if else within multidimensional php array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this

```
'sections'        => array(
  array(
    'title'       => 'License',
    'id'          => 'license'
    ),
  array(
    'title'       => 'General',
    'id'          => 'general'
    ),
  array(
    'title'       => 'Header',
    'id'          => 'header'
    ),
  array(
    'title'       => 'Footer',
    'id'          => 'footer'
    ),
  array(
    'title'       => 'Slider',
    'id'          => 'slider'
    ),
)
```

I would like to display only license tab if license is not valid. So I would like to use if else statement within array something like this

```
    'sections'        => array(
      array(
        'title'       => 'License',
        'id'          => 'license'
        ),

if ($license_valid) {
      array(
        'title'       => 'General',
        'id'          => 'general'
        ),
      array(
        'title'       => 'Header',
        'id'          => 'header'
        ),
      array(
        'title'       => 'Footer',
        'id'          => 'footer'
        ),
      array(
        'title'       => 'Slider',
        'id'          => 'slider'
        ),

  }
)
```

Can someone tell me the proper way to use that?

Comment: the only thing u could use is the [shorthand if](http://davidwalsh.name/php-ternary-examples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array = array(...);

if ($license_valid) {
   $additional = array(
    array(
        'title'       => 'General',
        'id'          => 'general'
        ),
      array(
        'title'       => 'Header',
        'id'          => 'header'
        ),
      array(
        'title'       => 'Footer',
        'id'          => 'footer'
        ),
      array(
        'title'       => 'Slider',
        'id'          => 'slider'
        ),
   );

   $array = array_merge($array, $additional)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But I have a very large array file. Is it possible to use if else using shorthand if else?.

Answer (score 0):

Well, array_merge is nice and all, but here's a different approach :

```
$arr = array('sections' => array(
    array(
        'title'       => 'License',
        'id'          => 'license'
    )
);

if ($license_valid) {
    $arr['sections'][] = array(
        'title'       => 'General',
        'id'          => 'general'
    );
    $arr['sections'][] = array(
        'title'       => 'Header',
        'id'          => 'header'
    );
    $arr['sections'][] = array(
        'title'       => 'Footer',
        'id'          => 'footer'
    );
    $arr['sections'][] = array(
        'title'       => 'Slider',
        'id'          => 'slider'
    );
}
```